# Return code of background process bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, process

How to get return value of background process?
If I do this, I will get 0

```
#!/bin/bash
SomeCommand&
echo $?
```

**output:** `#~0`

But if I try

```
SomeCommand
echo $?
```

**output:** `#~255`

I read, that wait command, but if I do that

```
SomeCommand$
wait $!
echo $?
```

I cannot run next command, if the previous command is not completed.

Comment: You can't get the exit status of a process if it's still working.  The `0` is saying you successfully started the job in the background.

Answer (score 6):

`wait` command waits for a given `background` job to complete. Use it like this:

```
( sleep 5; exit 4 ) &
wait $!

ret=$?
echo $ret
4
```

`$!` represents process id of the most recent background job.

In your case you can do:

```
SomeCommand &
wait $!
echo $?
```

To start multiple background jobs and retrieve their exit statuses later, save the value of `$!` after you start each job.

```
( sleep 5; exit 4 ) & b1_pid=$!
( sleep 5; exit 21 ) & b2_pid=$!

# More code

wait $b1_pid
b1_exit=$?
wait $b2_pid
b2_exit=$?
```

Comment: What if 10 background processes are launched? How to get return codes? Since there is no sense in launching one background process and wait for it.

Comment: `wait` command accepts a process id as argument. You can use `wait pid1` OR `wait pid2` etc.

Comment: @chepner: Thanks for adding the important edited part.

Comment: Is it possible to wait on multiple processes in parallel? e.g. `wait $pid1 &; wait $pid2 &`

Comment: `wait` accepts multiple process id if that is what you need.

Comment: If b2 finished earlier than b1, wait $b2_pid  will do nothing as b2 has been completed earlier. Will b2_exit be correct for such scenario?

Comment: `wait` will wait for a job to finish and if job has finished then it gets your correct exit code

Answer (score 0):

```
    #!/bin/bash
    command1 &
    commandN &
    for job in $(jobs -p)
    do
       wait $job
       echo $?
    done
```

Comment: While your code might (or not) work it would be great if you add a brief explanation about the error and how does your code solve it. As is it does not provide a full answer according to [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: What if there are unrelated jobs that have been launched before this script? `jobs -p` will show them and you script will wait for unrelated jobs

Comment: I test this script on my machine and `jobs -p` dont show unrelated jobs